# Как средствами delphi узнать какого типа proxy

Tags: delphi, proxy

То есть допустим у меня есть список проксей, как их прочекать я знаю, а вот как их раскидать по типам я не понимаю.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй через выбранный прокси подключиться через `http`, если не подключается-пробуй через сокет.

Answer (score 0):

Я в свое время использовал для этой цели библиотеку Synapse (да и вообще для работы с HTTP(s)). Небольшой пример проверки типа прокси [есть здесь](http://www.webdelphi.ru/2011/06/synapse-rabota-s-proksi/)